# React - pass prop that needs to be awaited for

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-props

Im trying to pass down from my component a prop that comes from an async function.

I have the following code:

```
export const Bar = (props: Props) => {
...
 const getValue = async () => {
    const { value } = await initValue();
    return  value;
  }
...
  return (
    <Foo value={getValue()}/> //Error in this line
}
```

TS throws an error:

> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key ts(2739)
> Blockquote

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you share what you intent to do with the value returned from `getValue()`

Comment: I think you can use a state to store the value and pass it to child, or use it to make a call in the child  and <Foo value={getValue}/> // getValue() => to getValue

Answer (score 0):

No need to call getValue(), just send it as a function variable then call it where is needed

```
   <Foo value={getValue}/>
```

In addition, in your case, the best way would be to set the value as a state and then send the value as props.